# Prevent ALL default animations/actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

OK, so I have a basic jQuery Mobile page.

What I need is : When user clicks on an element (e.g. the slider or a button)

- No animation should show
- No "action" should be enabled (like the slider moving etc)
- No colour changes should occur, like the button changing on hover

---

```
<!-- New Website #1 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style='min-height:0px;'>
    <head>
        <title>Website Title</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dev.css" />


    </head>

    <body id="jqm-website-3539" class=""  >


        <!-- New Page #1 -->
        <div data-role="page" comp-id="jqm-page-2862" id="jqm-page-2862" class="" data-add-back-btn="false" data-back-btn-text="" data-back-btn-theme="" data-dom-cache="false" data-theme="" data-title="" >

            <!-- New Header #1 -->
            <div data-role="header" comp-id="jqm-header-6813" id="jqm-header-6813" class="" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="false" data-theme="" >
                <h1></h1>
            </div>
            <!-- / New Header #1 -->

            <!-- New Content #1 -->
            <div data-role="content" comp-id="jqm-content-7853" id="jqm-content-7853" class="" data-theme=""  >

                <!-- New Button #1 -->
                <div comp-id="jqm-button-6345" >
                    <a data-role="button" id="jqm-button-6345" class="" data-corners="true" data-icon="" data-iconpos="left" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-mini="false" data-shadow="true" data-theme=""  href="#" data-transition="">
                        Button
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- / New Button #1 -->

                <!-- New Navigation Bar #1 -->
                <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed" id="jqm-navbar-5393" class="" data-iconpos="left"  >
                    <ul comp-id="jqm-navbar-5393" >

                    <!-- New Navigation Bar Item #1 -->
                    <li  >
                        <a comp-id="jqm-navbar-item-5974" href="#" id="jqm-navbar-item-5974" class="" data-icon="home" data-theme="" >
                            One
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- / New Navigation Bar Item #1 -->

                    <!-- New Navigation Bar Item #1 -->
                    <li  >
                        <a comp-id="jqm-navbar-item-5409" href="#" id="jqm-navbar-item-5409" class="" data-icon="plus" data-theme="" >
                            Two
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- / New Navigation Bar Item #1 -->

                    <!-- New Navigation Bar Item #1 -->
                    <li  >
                        <a  comp-id="jqm-navbar-item-925" href="#" id="jqm-navbar-item-925" class="" data-icon="gear" data-theme="" >
                            Three
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- / New Navigation Bar Item #1 -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- / New Navigation Bar #1 -->

                <!-- New SearchField #1 -->
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="searchinput" comp-id="jqm-input-search-9514" id="jqm-input-search-9514" class="" data-mini="false" data-theme=""  >
                    <input name="" placeholder="" value="" type="search">
                </div>
                <!-- / New SearchField #1 -->

                <!-- New Switch #1 -->
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="toggleswitch" comp-id="jqm-input-switch-2499" id="jqm-input-switch-2499" class="" data-highlight="false" data-mini="true" data-theme="" data-track-theme=""  >
                    <select data-role="slider">
                        <option value="0">
                            On
                        </option>
                        <option value="Off">
                            Off
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!-- / New Switch #1 -->

                <!-- New TextArea #1 -->
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="textarea" comp-id="jqm-text-area-8880" id="jqm-text-area-8880" class="" data-mini="false" data-theme=""  >
                    <label>

                    </label>
                    <textarea name="" placeholder="" id="jqm-text-area-8880" class="" data-mini="false" data-theme=""  ></textarea>
                </div>
                <!-- / New TextArea #1 -->

            </div>
            <!-- / New Content #1 -->
        </div>
        <!-- / New Page #1 -->

        <!-- New Page #1 -->
        <div data-role="page" comp-id="jqm-page-7022" id="jqm-page-7022" class="" data-add-back-btn="false" data-back-btn-text="" data-back-btn-theme="" data-dom-cache="false" data-theme="" data-title="" >

        </div>
        <!-- / New Page #1 -->


        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
        <script src="custom.js"></script>
        <script src="dev.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- / New Website #1 -->
```

Is this doable? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want nothing at all to happen, then just call event.preventDefault on click.

```
$("#button").click( function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you still want to perform some function, like linking to a URL, include it in your callback.

```
$("#button").click( function (event) {
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Well, this surely deals with the "disabling actions" part. What about the effects? If you hover over the button, the "effect" is still there. I'd need it to look like it should by without any other effects whatsoever... :-)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't turn off css hover effects with preventDefault. You'll need to add a class on hover, and then in your css file specify no hover effect when that class is present.

Answer (score 0):

If you're goal is to "disable" the whole page, you could overlay an (semi-)transparent div:

```
function disablePage() {
    $('body').append($('<div />').css({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%', 
        background: '#fff',
        position: 'fixed',
        zIndex: 999,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        opacity: .2 // or 0 for completely transparent
    }));
}
```

Comment: Well, but will the items below the overlay remain clickable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery(':animated') function

```
$('.btn1').click(function(){
    $('.one').animate({'width':'100%'},5000);
});
$('.btn2').click(function(){
    $('.two').animate({'width':'100%'},5000);
});
$('.btn3').click(function(){
    $('.three').animate({'width':'100%'},5000);
});

$('.all').click(function(){
    $(':animated').stop();
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KG7G6/)

Comment: This is a really interesting example. However, it's as irrelevant to the original question as it gets... :-)

Comment: You have not provided jquery so I have established my own. You can use your own selector and apply :animated selector to stop.

Comment: Buddy, what I asked has *nothing* to do with what you replied whatsoever. When a page is jQueryMobile-enabled, its elements are automatically "altered" by jQueryMobile (e.g. buttons when hovered have some special effects and so on). That's what I'm trying to disable.

Comment: "No animation should show
    No "action" should be enabled (like the slider moving etc)
    No colour changes should occur, like the button changing on hover"
This confused me ...... Should I delete the answer?